# Jquery and get values from form

Tags: jquery, forms, attr

I have little form for get the value from some field , but no get works finally , i put my code :

```
<script>
function pin_vps(id)
{

$('#form7').submit(function() {


var passpin = $('.pin_vps_'+id).attr("value");  

alert("ok "+passpin);

});

}
</script>


<?php
$v="18";
?>

<form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" action="?" onsubmit="pin_vps('<?php echo $v;?>');return false;">
<input name="pin_vps" type="text" class="pin_vps_<?php echo $v;?>"/>
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Access">
</form>
```

When i go and click in submit no happend nothing , i try use onclick in buttom and in form but continue no works

I don´t know what´s bad

Thank´s , Regards !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, so maybe providing some more information about your desired end result would help.

However I think the following should give you a head start:

HTML:

```
<form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" data-number="1" action="?">
    <input name="pin_vps" type="text" class="pin_vps_1" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Access" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form7").submit(function (e) {

        // Stop the form submitting so you can see the below
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the value of the field
        var dn = $(this).attr("data-number");
        var passpin = $(".pin_vps_" + dn, this).val();

        alert("ok " + passpin);

    });

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnKEf/2/